# Как передать во вложенный компонент аргумент используя связку React и Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Предположим у нас есть меню, у которого есть пункты, и нужно передать в основной компонент меню аргумент selectKey что бы подсветить активный пункт.

Вот пример

```
const Menu: React.FC<{activeKey: number}> & {Item: typeof Item} = ({
  children,
}) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Menu.Item = ({
  children,
}) => (
  <span>
    {children}
  </span>
);

const App = () => (
  <Menu activeKey={1}>
    <Menu.Item key={1}>Item 1</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 2</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 3</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

После того как написал вопрос, предположил, что такое скорее всего можно реализовать через Контекст

Comment: Я ж писал, как нормально этот код написать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, эту задачу можно решить через контекст